# Generate a hash for the keystore for facebook login. C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, powershell, facebook, xamarin.android

hey im making an app where you have to login via Facebook.

but when i try to make the hash for the keystore in CMD i get this error.

> Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline. And
> Unexpected token 'sha1' in expression or statement.

[image: Error]

all the guides i find say you have to use this command.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystorefile> | "C:\OpenSSl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I hope that someone can help.

Comment: Have you tried it in a command prompt instead of PowerShell?

Comment: Yes same result. @RetiredNinja

Comment: Add the call operator in front of the `openssl` path: `... | & "C:\OpenSSl\bin\openssl.exe" ...`